# Excel97 crash, Windows 7, VBA, DEP

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, dep

I've not be able to get Excel 97 VBA to run correctly on Win 7 without turning DEP entirely off. Access97 runs ok with just an Access DEP exception, But making Excel a DEP exception has not helped.

Specifically, Excel 97 crashes and closes when I (a) try to delete an add-in, or (b) call a Win32 API (even after I remove all the add-ins), or (c) use a Forms button (which is a call to a COM object).

I can (and have) remove all the add-ins by moving the files. I can (and have) remove all the unused references, including forms2.

Can you suggest any other DEP exclusions that might make Excel happy?

Comment: Buy a newer Office version. The 97 version is too old.

Comment: Use LibreOffice calc (free) Your only other hope is to add all EXE files inside of the MS Office folder to the exception list.

Comment: LibreOffice calc is like a 1997 shareware application compared to Excel.